# React Native Gifted Chat - message no showing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I using this module for simple chatting [React Native Gifted Chat](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat), and I try the example to send some message. But nothing is showing up in the screen (no bubble no text), I `console.log(this.state.messages);` inside the `render` function, array of message is there.

Example I used:

```
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';

class Example extends React.Component {

  state = {
    messages: [],
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      messages: [
        {
          _id: 1,
          text: 'Hello developer',
          createdAt: new Date(),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  onSend(messages = []) {
    this.setState((previousState) => ({
      messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GiftedChat
        messages={this.state.messages}
        onSend={(messages) => this.onSend(messages)}
        user={{
          _id: 1,
        }}
      />
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: any console errors ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi no error. just nothing showing up

Comment: hi mate , did you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you  need first import React and Component module:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
```

React Native Gifted Chat have nice working example with sending message: 
https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/tree/master/example

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that you are calling setState() inside componentWillMount(). Setting state in componentWillMount does not trigger re-rendering.

Move setState() to `ComponentDidMount()` or `constructor` method and it should re-render your component. Which means, GiftedChat will be loaded with message.
Refer to this doc for more info,
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: Could be, I have that code in ComponentDidMount as you say, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

use this definitely u will see the messages

use RenderBubble

in renderBubble function

check this condition ( sender id or current message user id )

```
currentMessage.user._id == this.state.senderData.id) { 
<Bubble 
{...props}
wrapperStyle={{ right: { height: 200, backgroundColor: 'blue', }, 
}} 
/>
} else {

<Bubble {...props} 
wrapperStyle={{ left: { backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0', },}}
 />
 }
```

that all in this code we differentiate the message in the left side or right side

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by not using SafeAreaView of react-native package

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).